# PHP remove last empty line in a textfile

Tags: php, regex, text-files

I have a problem with a textfile.
I have a textfile with an empty line (always the last line is empty).
I need to remove this line. I tried several ways. Here is my current way to delete empty lines:

```
function RemoveEmptyLines($filename)
{
    $myfile = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $Content = fread($myfile,filesize($filename));
    fclose($myfile);
    $NewContent = preg_replace('/^\s+/m', '', $Content);
    $myfile2 = fopen('new.txt', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile2, $NewContent);
    fclose($myfile2);
    echo "removed";
}
```

This deletes all the empty lines within the textfile, but not the last empty line.
If the content is:

> 1 \n 2 \n \n 3

It deletes the empty line.
If it is:

> 1 \n 2 \n 3 \n \n

It doesn´t..
Any solutions?
The problem is, that the file is dynamic, so I can´t just delete the last line, because it´s not always empty..

Answer (score 4):

Get the contents, trim the end and put the contents:

```
file_put_contents($filename, rtrim(file_get_contents($filename));
```

Or, for your existing code, you don't want `m` (PCRE_MULTILINE) and you want to match the end of the string `$`. I think this pattern will work:

```
/\s+$/
```

Both solutions will removes spaces as well.  If you don't want that:

```
/[\n\r]+$/
```

If you really want to delete ALL empty lines then you can read the file into an array, ignoring empty lines and put the contents back:

```
file_put_contents($filename, file($filename, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
```

However, if you are creating this file you might want to look at that code and not add the newline in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)? Might be what you need:

```
rtrim($NewContent);
```